# Advices on learning SDE/PDE for junior undergrad

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus, advice

Everyone. I am about to take an ODE Course in the summer. I wonder if it will help my understanding in stochastic differential equation and partial differential differential equation. My future plan is to work on some finance model like Black-Scholes pde. I saw people always talk these two things together. Black-Scholes pde we have two partial derivatives, however the sde only has time derivative, I wonder how things get connected. My academic advisor went on vacation and I wonder should I take differential geometry or numerical analysis too in the coming semester? Thanks and have a nice day.

Comment: Yes, I have just taken it.

Comment: @Potato Yes I have just taken it.

Comment: A course in basic differential equations will certainly help you in future if you want to work on PDEs and SDEs. Regarding course selection, you should consult with your academic advisor when s/he returns, since they will be able to advise you better than any anonymous person the internet (assuming they are any good...)

Comment: @Potato duder thanks man.

Comment: (Of course, there is the possibility that your academic advisor will not be able to advise you appropriately, especially if they are not a mathematician, in which case you should feel free to ask a new question.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear what you're asking:

> I am about to take an ODE Course in the summer. I wonder if it will help my understanding in stochastic differential equation and partial differential differential equation.

Yes, absolutely. I wouldn't recommend pursuing those topics without a introduction to ODE. Taking ODE this summer is the place to start; I hope that's the main point of your question. Good choice.

> My academic advisor went on vacation and I wonder should I take differential geometry or numerical analysis too in the coming semester?

If your question is about taking either of these two classes this summer, I would wait on that to consult with your advisor when s/he returns. Apart from recommending and/or confirming you choice to take ODE this summer, I don't know that we're in the best position to guide you. If the classes you refer to are offered this summer (if you mean "summer term" when you allude to "the coming term": then if you have met the courses' prerequisites, and have the *time*, *financial ability*, and a strong *desire* to take one or the other, *along with ODE*, by all means, go for it. But regarding what you "should take": It is hard to know if "math" is your major or one of your majors, or if you are pursuing a degree in finance. And in either case, the decision about prioritizing among the math classes you plan to take prior to graduation can wait until you have the chance to discuss the matter with your advisor.

Comment: $\Large\color{red}{+1}$&$\Large\color{green}{✔}^\color{red}{✿}$ @amWhy

Comment: @amWhy: Gets another thumbs up from me! +1

Comment: @faranak50 how to type those emoticons here plz?

Comment: @TonyStark: \Large\color{green}{✔}^\color{red}{✿}

Comment: @faranak50: Thanks and hope you can overcome your exams today. :-)